# Passing instance method result to class attribute

Tags: python, django

Let's say I have two models, the first referencing a third `User` model:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
...

class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        Parent,
        limit_choices_to={'user': get_user()}
    )

    def get_user(self):
        return self.request.user
```

I want to limit choices for the child model to instances bound to current user. One way to do it would be to pass the `request` to the `form` class and solve it inside `__init__`, but it present's other limitations. Is there a way to do this inside the model class, kind of like in the example above?

Comment: What are the limitations?

Comment: @bdbd. Ok, "limitations" might have been a bad choice of a word. More inconvenience, llike when you have to repeat the same code in different form classes. But really I am just curious. I'm a beginner coder, and I'm trying to understand  if it's possible to reference a class method's return in class attribute.